# Tried to send email from in-app and doesn't work - Swift (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, email, in-app

I tried 2 codes from different sites to **send an email from my iOS app**.
When I press the *Send* button it calls the method **mailComposeController** and always returns me the log "Mail sent" as the *result* parameter is always **MFMailComposeResultSent.value**, even when I have my iPhone 5S in *airplane mode*.

Besides this, even when I have internet connection, **I never receive the email**. Already checked SPAM and other folders and waited one entire day if it was delayed but never received even trying several times.

I program with Swift and use XCode 6.4 in a Macbook Pro retina from mid-2014 with Yosemite 10.10.5.

Here the Swift code:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if (MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()) {

            var emailTitle = "Vea Software Feedback"

            var messageBody = "Vea Software! :)"

            var toRecipents = ["oscar.muntal@gmail.com"]

            var mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self

            mc.setSubject(emailTitle)

            mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)

            mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)

            self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }else {

            println("No email account found")

        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Email Delegate
    func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError) {

        switch result.value {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.value:
            println("Mail cancelled")
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved.value:
            println("Mail saved")
        case MFMailComposeResultSent.value:
            println("Mail sent")
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed.value:
            println("Mail sent failure: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        default:
            break
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

for me the following code works perfectly fine:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
      let toRecipents = ["oscar.muntal@gmail.com"]
      let emailTitle = "Vea Software Feedback"
      let messageBody = "Vea Software! :)"

      let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
      mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
      mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
      mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
      mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)

      presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
      print("cannot send mails")
    }
  }

  func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    switch result {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
      print("Mail cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
      print("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
      print("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
      print("Mail sent failure: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    default:
      break
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: btw: are you testing in simulator or on a real device?

Comment: I am testing on my real device iPhone 5S.

Comment: Did you receive in your email inbox the message sent? (in the code you paste there's my email in there).

Comment: of course i put MY email in it. :) and i received the mails, yeah. did you try my code? especially i changed some stuff in the mailcomposecontroller delegate method...

Comment: you use let and the op uses var

Comment: yeah. i changed that since the mailcomposecontroller does not get changed. no need for `var`.

Comment: Andre Slotta, I tried your code but it gives me errors in the 4 lines of every case in the switch in mailComposeController() method. 
The error is: 
Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to two MFMailComposeResult operands

Comment: I also tried to change the "var" into "let" in my code and send the message but still doesn't receive anything in my mailbox :(

Comment: ok, seems like you are not working with swift 2. can you add **mcc@dodgemail.de** to the recipients list and try to send again with your old code? just to make sure that your email is not the problem...

Comment: Ok, I've sent you to: mcc@dodgemail.de
Did you receive it?
I'm using Swift. How can I use Swift2? Thank you.

Comment: ok, did not receive anything. but you can send mails from your iphone generally?

Comment: Yes, i send emails every day from my iPhone's Gmail app.

Comment: gmail app does not mean that you have a mail account that your mailcomposecontroller can use! when you open the regular mail app on your iphone. do you have any mail account to send mails there?

Comment: Woah!! Problem solved! That was the problem! I didn't have associated my email account to the native iOS email app for the "Mail" purposes but only for the "Contacts", "Calendars" and "Notes". 
Thank you very very much Adre Slotta!!! :)
P.S. It worked also with my initial code and "var" instead of "let".

Comment: yeah. i know that `var` was not causing the error. but since you do not change the controller afterwards you could and should use `let` i think. you're welcome. glad i could help. :)

Comment: I answered myself saying which was the problem but I don't know how to close this issue in Stackoverflow. Can I or the admin will do it? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Andre Slotta I solved my problem.

The problem was that I didn't have enabled the "Mail" Switch in the Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendar > myemailaccount.

This enables to send and receive emails from the native iOS app. Instead of this I just had this enabled for the "Contacts", "Calendars" and "Notes", and use the Gmail iOS app for the Email purposes in my iPhone.

It worked with my initial code also, so it wasn't a code problem at all and everyone can try my initial code in Swift (not Swift2).

Thanks again Andre Slotta for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please add you email account in your mobile phone Setting!